# How to write Laravel Query in two parts

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working with Laravel 5.2. I want to write a query in two parts like this:

```
$getData =  DB::table($table)
            ->where($where);
$getData->first();

return $getData;
```

But it is not working for me. It Not provides correct data to me.

It gives:

```
Array ( [aggregate] => [columns] => [distinct] => [from] => countries [joins] => [wheres] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [type] => Nested [query] => Array ( [aggregate] => [columns] => [distinct] => [from] => countries [joins] => [wheres] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [type] => Basic [column] => country_name [operator] => = [value] => India [boolean] => and ) ) [groups] => [havings] => [orders] => [limit] => [offset] => [unions] => [unionLimit] => [unionOffset] => [unionOrders] => [lock] => ) [boolean] => and ) ) [groups] => [havings] => [orders] => [limit] => 1 [offset] => [unions] => [unionLimit] => [unionOffset] => [unionOrders] => [lock] => )
```

But it works correctly when i call like this:

```
$getData =  DB::table($table)
                ->where($where)->first();
return $getData;
```

Can we not call a query in two parts in laravel.

Comment: what is the error ? try return $getData->first();

Comment: Error is not coming but now it is not giving correct data to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get back the returned data from `$getData->first();`

```
$getData =  DB::table($table)
              ->where($where);
$getData = $getData->first(); // <----

return $getData;
```